# Android Studio stuck at Gradle Build Running, showing time out while waiting for slave aapt process error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I am getting the following errors while building gradle.

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also while executing the aapt.exe file opens up in DOS and shows the text "Ready" and gets stuck there.

[image]

I am on Windows 7 having Android Studio version 2.3.3
Gradle version: 3.3
buildtoolversion: 26.0.1
Android plugin version: 2.3.3

Also all image files in drawable folder is showing as .png format.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error is clear, something in your system is freezing aapt. What about this? `Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds`  Did you temporarily disabled antivirus? Did you added time to your SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT enviroment variable?

Comment: @martin There is no antivirus installed in my system. Even I have turned firewall off. I have set SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to 60. I have also tried setting it to 30 and also deleting the variable. But still nothing comes up. Did you know any other reason which could cause it?

Comment: No, i don't know any reason for this. But what I know for a fact is that if you run aapt.exe without options it will respond with a complete help of the command usage. Maybe your aapt is corrupt for some reason. Reinstalling (in fact uninstalling and reinstalling) latest Build Tools again fron the SDK Manager could help to know if that is the problem. Did it work OK before throwing this error?

Comment: Yes I tried uninstall and reinstall but nothing happened...do you have any idea about the png-cruncher error...I'm getting the error from 1 to 5 only as shown in question

Comment: Are you trying to build a signed apk? If so, confirm that your Keystore password and Key password are correct.